# SQL redundant databases both sets being modified independently yet staying concurrent

Tags: sql-server, data-synchronization

I have a server in location 1. This location has slow external internet but all the employees. Location 2 has fast external internet but no people are there. I have a mobile app that I would like to connect to location 2 and have an instantaneous sync. between the two databases. What is the proper way to do this? If a field is updated at site 1 the server sends it to 2. If 2 is modified it sends it to site 1. The last change is always used.

Comment: Have you read about synchronous replication? Would this work for this case? If not please edit your question to explain why not.

Comment: That is more what I was looking for I think!

Comment: Does MSSQL Server do this natively?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has various [flavours of replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx) with different capabilities.

It sounds like [peer-to-peer transactional replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx) best fits your needs.

Comment: is there an option where both are masters? each data set will be edited from local area. one will have iis and the others are in a LAN setting with slow internet.